# how to make a border shadow while others have sharp borders

Tags: css

i'm trying to add shadow effect only for single border while other borders have sharp borders. Does CSS has this power or are there other techniques i don't know?

```
#panel {
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 10px #00c6ff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px #00c6ff;
    box-shadow:0 1px 10px #00c6ff;
    width:25%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#161616;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="panel">
<p>Panel Content</p>
</div>
```

i'm trying to do something like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `box-shadow`, you could use a :pseudo-element with `linear-gradient`.

```css
#panel {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #161616;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#panel:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top : -10px;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #00c6ff, #00c6ff calc(100% - 20px), rgba(0, 198, 255, 0));
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
  <p>Panel Content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
box-shadow: 0px -8px 5px -5px #00c6ff;
```

The fourth value is the spread radius. Positive values will cause the shadow to expand and grow bigger, negative values will cause the shadow to shrink. If not specified, it will be 0 (the shadow will be the same size as the element).

So basically you make the shadow smaller than your box, and make sure it sticks out on one side only.

shadows are not related to borders. They are independent of each other. There's no such thing as a "border shadow".

Comment: not actually 100% sharp or at least 98% sharp edges, is it possible to hide other borders one way or another ?

Comment: If the shadow fits completely under the box, it will be 100% sharp.